# How do I call back a function in this code?

Tags: python, function

I have a task for my Python Course. I have to write a function that calculates the absolute value and returns the absolute value of a number. I was able to get it to work, but it only works when I add the last line, which isn't supposed to be there. I'm not sure how to call the function without that last bit. Any tips?

```
def absolute(a):
    a = float(input('Enter a positive or negative number: '))
    if a >= 0:
        print ('The absolute value of', a, 'is:', a)
    if a < 0:
        print('The absolute value of', a, 'is:', a*(-1))
              
print ( 'The absolute value of 1 is', absolute(1) )
```

Comment: printing and returning aren't the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "It only works when I add the last line"? What was the original version of the code? What happened when you ran it? And what did you want instead?

Comment: Also, as Julien says, your function doesn't "return the absolute value" . It prints it. I suggest you read about the `return` keyword.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to call the function without that last bit." The only part that you have here that calls the function is `absolute(1)`, The rest of the last line prints out some message. These are two separate and distinct things that you combine in a single line of code. In order to do the calculations in a function, you MUST call it with `absolute(x)` where `x` can be a constant, a variable, or a complex expression. But you DON'T have to include this inside of `print()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is doing unnecessary work by asking for input as well as checking whether it is a positive or negative.

My approach:

```
def absolute(num):
  if num >= 0:
    return num
  else:
    return num * -1
```

Define another function that will process number provided by the user:

```
def process_num():
  a = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
  print(f'The absolute value of {a} is {absolute(a)}')
```

Then, just call the `process_num()` to run the function.

Pic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your code is what's actually calling the function. Without it, you've defined a function but aren't using it anywhere. The last line is what's actually using the function.

EDIT: if you are meant to be returning the value, you should include a `return` statement at the end of the function. Right now you're just printing a statement, which isn't returning anything.

Comment: No that function isn't 'correct' as per OP's instructions: it returns nothing.

Comment: Good catch -- I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: so how do I return the function without it? I'm a little stuck on that part. It seems to be an easy concept I just can't grasp it.

Comment: @CurryPacket First, it sounds like you need to read more about functions and the `return` keyword. You are using terminology incorrectly. While you can "return a function" that has nothing to do with what you are trying to do here. Instead, you need to return the result of the absolute value calculation. Another thing that will help is to use very precise language. When you say "without it" what "it" are you referring to? Be as specific and precise as you can be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of your code:

```
def absolute():
    a = float(input('Enter a positive or negative number: '))
    if a >= 0:
        return ('The absolute value of', a, 'is:', a)
    if a < 0:
        return('The absolute value of', a, 'is:', a*(-1))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your function just prints the value. Return and print are two different things.
And this is how you print the value on both types.

```
def AbsoluteValue(a):
    return abs(a)

def Abs(a):
    print(abs(a))

n = float(input())
print(AbsoluteValue(n))  
Abs(n)
```